# Show taskbar button when using WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW

Tags: winapi, createwindowex

Is it possible to display the taskbar button when WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW flag is used in `CreateWindowEx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style is required for an unowned top-level window to display itself on the Taskbar.

The [Extended Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) documentation specifically states that a "*tool window does not appear in the taskbar*".

MSDN further documents this in more detail:

[The Taskbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179.aspx)

> The Shell places a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates an unowned window—that is, a window that does not have a parent and that **has the appropriate extended style bits** (see [Managing Taskbar Buttons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179.aspx#Managing_Taskbar_But), below).
>
> ...
>
> Managing Taskbar Buttons
>
> The Shell creates a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates a window that isn't owned. **To ensure that the window button is placed on the taskbar, create an unowned window with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style. To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended style**. As an alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible window.
>
> The Shell will remove a window's button from the taskbar only if the window's style supports visible taskbar buttons. If you want to dynamically change a window's style to one that does not support visible taskbar buttons, you must hide the window first (by calling `ShowWindow` with `SW_HIDE`), change the window style, and then show the window.
>
> ...
>
> Modifying the Contents of the Taskbar
>
> [Version 4.71 and later](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776779.aspx) of Shell32.dll adds the capability to modify the contents of the taskbar. **From an application, you can now add, remove, and activate taskbar buttons**. Activating the item does not activate the window; it shows the item as pressed on the taskbar.
>
> The taskbar modification capabilities are implemented in a Component Object Model (COM) object (`CLSID_TaskbarList` ) that exposes the [`ITaskbarList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652.aspx) interface (`IID_ITaskbarList`). You must call the [`ITaskbarList::HrInit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774650.aspx) method to initialize the object. You can then use the methods of the `ITaskbarList` interface to modify the contents of the taskbar.

So, you might be able to use [`ITaskbarList::AddTab()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774646.aspx) for your tool window:

> **Any type of window can be added to the taskbar**, but it is recommended that the window at least have the `WS_CAPTION` style.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to use the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style but using WS_EX_APPWINDOW to display the button?

Comment: @Dementor The two styles cannot be mixed together. However, you might try using `ITaskbarList::AddTab()`. I updated my answer.