# How to hide App from ALT+TAB but not from the Taskbar (icon row)

Tags: delphi, winapi

I want to hide my App from ALT+TAB but not from the Taskbar;
The taskbar has a icon now OK that can be used to manage the tool GUI.

However, there is no need to have the app in ALT-TAB browsable window list as the main window of app is actually hidden.

The App Window is hidden by setting its ALPHA to 0.

Comment: I suggest you could try to add the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` extended window style.To mark an application window as a tool window.  A tool window does not appear in the dialog that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB.

Comment: Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle and WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;

Just added this as recommended but it made no difference..

Comment: @Tom: To set a bit, you use `or`, not `and`.

Comment: Thanks, but this row makes no difference to ALT-TAB behaviour;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;

Comment: Adding the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` style will likely remove the window from the Taskbar, not just the Alt-Tab dialog.  You would have to use [`ITaskbarList.AddTab()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist-addtab) to put the window back on the Taskbar.

Comment: Currently WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW displays my app on both Taskbar and ALT-TAB view.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/551847/11872808

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out,  I need that icon appears on taskbar, while its not shown in ALT+TAB, so need to investigate this more,  hopefully someone would have a Delphi 7 compatible solution, the Delphi has Application class that may affect to above C solution.

Comment: @RemyLebeau We have a good answer with ITaskbarList.AddTab() but it's not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to set your `Form.BorderStyle` to either `bsSizeToolWin` or `bsToolWindow`, so its window is not listed in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dialog.
2. You have to do the same for the `Application.Handle` window:

   ```delphi
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate( Sender: TObject );
   var
     iStyle: Integer;
   begin
     iStyle:= GetWindowLong( Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE );
     SetWindowLong( Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, iStyle or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW );
   end;
   ```

   Steps #1 and #2 work for me as expected: nothing in the window list, not one button on the taskbar.
3. As per Remy to add a taskbar button alone [the interface promises to do so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist-addtab):

   ```delphi
   uses
     ComObj;

   // From https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/master/jvcl/run/JvProgressBar.pas
   const
     CLSID_TaskbarList: TGUID= '{56FDF344-FD6D-11d0-958A-006097C9A090}';

   type
     ITaskbarList= interface(IUnknown)
       ['{56FDF342-FD6D-11D0-958A-006097C9A090}']
       function HrInit: HRESULT; stdcall;
       function AddTab( hwnd: HWND ): HRESULT; stdcall;
       function DeleteTab( hwnd: HWND ): HRESULT; stdcall;
       function ActivateTab( hwnd: HWND ): HRESULT; stdcall;
       function SetActiveAlt( hwnd: HWND ): HRESULT; stdcall;
     end;

   var
     oBar: ITaskbarList= nil;

   procedure TForm1.Button1Click( Sender: TObject );
   begin
     if oBar= nil then begin  // Never used? Try to init.
       oBar:= CreateComObject( CLSID_TaskbarList ) as ITaskbarList;
       if oBar.HrInit<> S_OK then oBar:= nil;  // Failed? Can't use it.
     end;
     if oBar<> nil then begin
       if oBar.AddTab( self.Handle )= S_OK then self.Caption:= 'Success!';
     end;
   end;
   ```

   However: this 3rd step didn't work for me on Win7 - no button was added to the taskbar, although no error occurred. It may be because

   - I have disabled styles and my taskbar looks like in Win95, and
   - [T-Clock Redux 2.4.4](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases/tag/v2.4.4#492-rc) is manipulating it.

I discourage this entire approach: what appears in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should also have a taskbar button and vice versa. At work there's this annoying [NCP software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCP_Engineering) which auto hides its window upon successful connect, insists on using a tasktray icon and auto-slides in a window as soon as I come near the taskicon, although I surely wanted to hit a different one. Horrible, because it's always in the way and can't be relied on to persist either.

That's not what you intend, but you also want to force inconsistency. Simply don't. Just release an application that can be used and where expected behavior also happens. If all that doesn't move you then think of how prone your application will be in the future to fail in emulations - don't do unusual stuff and [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_(software)) will have no problems running it for all Unix users, too.

Comment: Thanks for the high quality answer, I will test if it solves my issue, sure the goal is not to be annoying GUI;   My app also has a TaskTray icon option for power-users, but nowadays novice users do not even know where these icons are located.

Comment: I can confirm that the window is now totally hidden, unfortunately the code does not seem to create a taskbar button (Win11), any other ideas how to create that?

Comment: I found this ticket but still not clear for me how to achieve this behaviour:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351633/show-taskbar-button-when-using-ws-ex-toolwindow

Comment: The [comment to that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351633/show-taskbar-button-when-using-ws-ex-toolwindow#comment71854766_42351679) makes clear it is impossible in any other way than using `ITaskbarList`.

Comment: FYI, you should call `oBar.HrInit` only once, when  creating the `ITaskbarList` object. If the Taskbar gets recreated (ie, after an Explorer crash/restart), you have to recreate the object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, totally right. Was never meant for production anyway. Edited it in.